# Get children of an XHPChild

Tags: hhvm, hacklang, xhp

I am trying to move my website to Hack and XHP, of course. Below is a structure of what code structure I want to achieve:

```
<ui:backstageHeader>
  <ui:backstageHeader-navItem href="/">stories</ui:backstageHeader-navItem>
  <ui:backstageHeader-navItem href="/story/send">send a story</ui:backstageHeader-navItem>
  <ui:backstageHeader-navItem href="/aboutus">support</ui:backstageHeader-navItem>
</ui:backstageHeader>
```

(**Note:** `:ui:backstageHeader-navItem` basically renders to `<a href={$this->:href}>{$this->getCHildren}</a>` so there is not need to attach its class here.)

Below is the code for `:ui:backstageHeader`:

```
final class :ui:backstageHeader extends :ui:base {
  attribute :div;
  children (:ui:backstageHeader-navItem)*;

  protected function compose() {
    $dom =
    <section class="backstage-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="cell-logo">
          <a href="/">
            <span class="no23-logo-white"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="cell-navigation">
        </div>
        <div class="cell-account">
          <div class="cell-login">
            <div id="siteNav-login">Autentificare</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>;
    $mainContainer = $dom->getChildren("div")[0];
    $cellNavigation = $mainContainer->getChildren("div")[1];
    $navItems = <ul class="main-navigation"></ul>;
    foreach($this->getChildren() as $child) {
      $navItems->appendChild(<li>{$child}</li>);
    }
    $dom->appendChild($navItems);

    return $dom;
  }
}
```

I used the Terminal to debug my code using `hhvm -m d <file.php>`, and everything was alright there; however, when I get to my browser, I get `500` error header. This is what the log says:

```
Catchable fatal error: Hack type error: Could not find method getChildren in an object of type XHPChild at /var/www/res/ui/backstage-header.php line 25
```

The error comes from

```
$cellNavigation = $mainContainer->getChildren("div")[1];
```

But, somehow, I need to append `ul.main-navigation` to `div.cell-navigation` from my `section.backstage-header`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't structure your code this way. Built it up from the inside out, so that you don't have to do a ton of unreadable `getChildren` calls looking for specific children. Those calls are super hard to read, and super inflexible when you change the structure of your XHP. You wouldn't do something like `node.firstChild.lastChild.lastChild.firstChild` in the JS DOM, would you? No, there's a better way in JS, to find things by class or ID; in XHP, you can just build it up the right way in the first place!

I'd give you an example of this, but it doesn't look like you actually *use* `$mainContainer` or `$cellNavigation`, so you can just remove those two problematic definitions.

As an aside, you really shouldn't be getting your type errors as catchable fatals from HHVM; this is a last resort sort of check. Try running the `hh_client` checker directly, maybe even showing its result in your IDE; it will give you a much faster iteration cycle, and much more information than HHVM provides.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, appendChild is very prone to human error. It's easier to do something like:

```
$items = (new Vector($this->getChildren()))->map($child ==> <li>{$child}</li>);
return <div id="container">{$items}</div>;
```

If you want to wrap the children in `<li />`.

Not sure if that will work but it will be close.

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: You can assign variables from within an XHP tree.

```
$root =
  <div>
    {$child = <span>
      Text children
    </span>}
  </div>;
```

Now $child is already set to the `<span>` element.